# Overriding the JSF converter javax.faces.convert.BigDecimalConverter in favor of a custom converter using @FacesConverter(forClass = BigDecimal.class)

Tags: jsf, converters, bigdecimal

I have the following general `BigDecimal` converter (deeply reviewing the code is absolutely superfluous).

```
@FacesConverter(value = "bigDecimalConverter")
public class BigDecimalConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private CurrencyRateBean currencyRateBean; // Maintains a currency selected by a user in his/her session.

    private static final int scale = 2; // Taken from an enum.

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (!StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(value);
            return bigDecimal.scale() > scale ? bigDecimal.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros() : bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Message"), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        BigDecimal newValue;
        if (value instanceof Long) {
            newValue = BigDecimal.valueOf((Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            newValue = BigDecimal.valueOf((Double) value);
        } else if (!(value instanceof BigDecimal)) {
            throw new ConverterException("Message");
        } else {
            newValue = (BigDecimal) value;
        }

        final String variant = (String) component.getAttributes().get("variant");

        if (variant != null) {
            if (variant.equalsIgnoreCase("grouping")) {
                DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                formatter.setGroupingUsed(true);
                formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(scale);
                formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(scale);
                return formatter.format(newValue);

            } else if (variant.equalsIgnoreCase("currency")) {
                String currency = currencyRateBean.getCurrency();
                DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", new String(currency.substring(0, 2))));
                formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols());
                formatter.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(currency));
                return formatter.format(newValue);
            }
        }

        DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        formatter.setGroupingUsed(false); // Not necessary.
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(scale);
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(scale);
        return formatter.format(newValue);
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:converter converterId="bigDecimalConverter"/>
    <f:attribute name="variant" value="grouping"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Depending upon the value of `variant` in `<f:attribute>`, it converts the value to either currency equivalent ($123) or a value using groups (11,111). Other criteria may also be defined as and when required i.e separate converters for other types of formats, if any, are not required. The default task of the converter is to round up the value to two decimal points.

In order to avoid mentioning of,

```
<f:converter converterId="bigDecimalConverter"/>
```

or `converter="#{bigDecimalConverter}"` everywhere, the converter class needs to be decorated with,

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = BigDecimal.class)
```

Doing so, JSF takes its own [`javax.faces.convert.BigDecimalConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/BigDecimalConverter.html) beforehand. I have tried extending that class but it did not make any difference.

Is it possible to override the default JSF `javax.faces.convert.BigDecimalConverter` so that our own converter can be used by specifying `forClass = BigDecimal.class` so that there is no need to fiddle around with `<f:converter converterId="bigDecimalConverter"/>` or `converter="#{bigDecimalConverter}"` anywhere?

Comment: You might want to start by setting the constant [`CONVERTER_ID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/BigDecimalConverter.html#CONVERTER_ID) on your converter implementation, being that that's what the runtime uses to register the standard converters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, overriding default converters (and validators, components and renderers) can't take place with annotations on the same identifier(s). It really has to be explicitly registered in webapp's own `faces-config.xml`.

In case you intend to override `converter="javax.faces.BigDecimal"`, then do so:

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>javax.faces.BigDecimal</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.example.YourBigDecimalConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

In case you intend to override implicit conversion for type `java.math.BigDecimal`, then do so:

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>java.math.BigDecimal</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.example.YourBigDecimalConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

You need the latter.

Comment: If this converter class is packaged inside the same package as the default converter i.e `javax.faces.convert.BigDecimalConverter`, then it should have a higher class loading preference and the container should load this custom class. Why doesn't doing so the thing happen ?

Comment: It should. I can't try for you right now due to lack of an IDE workspace, but it really should. Perhaps the build was still dirty. If you ping me later, I will come back on this.

Comment: Yep, it just works for me with latest Mojarra and Tomcat.

Comment: Yes. Using a test case, Tomcat 8.0.9.0 succeeds ; GlassFish 4.1 fails. Since this is not a functional requirement, I can silently ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing default converters should follow the,uh, following steps:

1. Extend the default converter that you plan to replace, to avoid class casting exception. In your case this would be the `javax.faces.convert.BigDecimalConverter`
2. Register your converter in a *faces-config.xml*, specifying a `<converter-id>` that corresponds to the default. This allows you to override the default. What you'll have in effect is:

   ```
        <converter>
            <converter-class> 
                 com.you.YourBigDecimalConverter
            </converter-class> 
            <converter-id>
                 javax.faces.BigDecimal
            </converter-id>
       </converter>
   ```

Comment: JSF still takes its own converter. In other words, these changes do not make any difference. :)

Comment: What build are you using @Tiny? These are the recommended steps from the JSF spec

Comment: It is Mojarra 2.2.12. I have also tried using the same fully qualified class name as the in-built converter (`javax.faces.convert.BigDecimalConverter`) to give it a higher class loading preference on a blank playground project having a single XHTML file and least possible dependencies but to no avail.